# Enable textbox based on the dropdown value

Tags: knockout.js

I am displaying a list of customers. Columns are CustomerName , Designation and OtherBox. CustomerName is label, Desingations is a drop Down and otherBox is a textbox. In Designations drop down i am displaying text as 'Professional' and 'others'. If the user select 'Others' then i need enable the OtherBox which a textbox to enter values. If the user  reselects as 'professional 'in the drop down then the OtherBox should be disabled. Basically the OtherBox will be enable disable based o the dropdown value. Below is the sample code. Please let me know how it can be done..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm7" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
                <table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="tblEncode">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                          <th>Others</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
                        <tr>
                            <td ><span data-bind="text: CustName"></span></td>
                            <td><select name="ddlUsers" data-bind="options: Designation,  optionsText: 'DesignationName', optionsValue: 'DesignationId'"></select></td>
                           <td> <input type="text"  data-bind="text: OtherBox, enable: BoxDisable" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>

function UserViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.customers = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.Designations = ko.observableArray([]);

  function addCustomer(custId, custName, designation, otherBox, boxDisable) {
    return {
      CustId: ko.observable(custId),
      CustName: ko.observable(custName),
      Designation: ko.observable(designation),
      OtherBox: ko.observable(otherBox),
      BoxDisable: ko.observable(boxDisable)
    }
  }

  function addDesignation(designationId, designationName) {
    return {
      DesignationId: ko.observable(designationId),
      DesignationName: ko.observable(designationName)
    }
  }

  self.Designations().push(new addDesignation(1, 'Select  designation'));
  self.Designations().push(new addDesignation(1, 'Professional'));
  self.Designations().push(new addDesignation(2, 'Others'));

  var cust1 = new addCustomer(1, 'j', self.Designations(), null, false);
  self.customers.push(cust1)

  cust1 = new addCustomer(2, 'k', self.Designations(), null, false);
  self.customers.push(cust1)







}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var userModel = new UserViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(userModel);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textbox's readonly status depends on the dropdown's value. **So you have to track the dropdown value and change the textbox's status** (Of course you shouldn'tdo it manually but via an knockout observable).

In your code, you are passing an boolean value for disabling the textbox but you change it nowhere. That's the problem.

I have edit some of your code and make it run here https://codepen.io/trgiangvp3/pen/eyOvQz

```js
  function addCustomer(custId, custName, designation, otherBox, currentDesignationId) {
    return {
      CustId: ko.observable(custId),
      CustName: ko.observable(custName),
      Designation: ko.observable(designation),
      OtherBox: ko.observable(otherBox),
      CurrentDesignationId:  ko.observable(currentDesignationId)
    }
  }
```

```html
<td><select name="ddlUsers" data-bind="options: Designation, optionsText: 'DesignationName', optionsValue: 'DesignationId', value: CurrentDesignationId"></select></td>
<td><input type="text" data-bind="text: OtherBox, enable: CurrentDesignationId() == 2" /></td>
```

But I think your code is really bad implemented as it has no coding convention and the model structure is not clear. Very hard to read.

**Update:** I have create another CodePen for a better implementation. You might take a look [Better implementation](https://codepen.io/trgiangvp3/pen/WdejGQ)

Comment: thanks for the reply. However i do not want to use : optionsText: 'DesignationName'.. It should be default to the first Option 'Professional'

Comment: `optionsText: 'DesignationName'` is what you are using, I have nothing to do with it. If you don't want to use optionsText: 'DesignationName' anymore then just do what you want. I've just solved the very first problem as you said that you can't make your code to run.
Also, I have created another CodePen which is better implemented to your case. You should take a look at it (see the Update part above).

Comment: sorry for the typo errors.. i do not want to use optionsCaption: 'Choose Designation'. It should be default first option